# Superfluous scrollbars

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow, opera

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb6pk/) I have a 100% height div with content that overflows horizontally. it works as intended in IE, Firefox, and Chrome but Opera creates a vertical scrollbar to scroll the distance covered by the horizontal scroll bar. Is there a way to avoid this?

`overflow-y:hidden` kinda works but the div is still stretching underneath the horizontal scrollbar.

```
<html><body><div id="filler"><div id="scroller"></div></div></body></html>

#filler{
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        overflow:auto;
    }
#scroller{
        height:100%;
        width:2000px;    
        }
```

[image: comparison image]

Comment: I think I understand what you're describing after carefully reading it a couple times.  Perhaps you can post a screen-shot to remove any doubt.  Thanks.

Comment: sure i'll make a comparison

Comment: Have you tried specifying `overflow-x: auto` and `overflow-y: auto` separately? Though, it may simply be that the horizontal scrollbar offsets the page height by about `17px` in Opera... and judging by the remaining area on the vertical scrollbar, that seems pretty likely.

Comment: yeah all other browsers stretch the div up to the scrollbar. opera on the other hand lays the scrollbar ontop and then attaches the vertical one so the covered content can be seen. i cant imagine a scenario where this is desirable.

Comment: This seems more like a browser bug in Opera than anything wrong with your code.

Comment: it does seem like a bug. i was hoping someone would know a solution that avoids the weird scrollbar behavior